# Where is the C library wrapper function of fopen written?

Tags: c, system-calls

I want to know what happen when compiler encountered "fopen()" in C program.
Where is the function which calls the 'open' system call?
I see fopen() is declared in stdio.h, but I cannot find where it is implemented!!
I want to see where system call number and other parameters of system calls are written to CPU registers.

Thank you.

Comment: it's implemented in your standard library. What system and compiler are you using?

Comment: It depends on your platform. [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is common, but there are many others.

Comment: I am using gcc on linux kernel 4.0.9

Comment: Download glibc sources and read. This is mot an easy task though.

Comment: The kernel isn't particularly relevant here: This is a user-space library, and there are a number of possible choices for distributions to use. In fact, some distributions offer a choice.

Comment: FYI, definition is equivalent to implementation; declaration is the correct term.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at `glibc` implementation here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofopen.c;h=be2bbb663bc04093493313af266fcdad85c62c28;hb=HEAD#l95

`_IO_new_fopen` is a symbolic constant (macro) that expands to `fopen` The `fopen` function is a wrapper around an internal function to a `libio` function.

`fopen` isn't a *system* call, you might be confusing it with `open` which is a system call.